# How to stop progressbar spinning after connection has been lost in Android

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

When I pressed back button on the mobile phone after that I switch off the wifi or mobile data network.

*Progress bar spinning does not get stop and back button does not work.*

```
    protected void onRefreshingStateChanged(boolean refreshing) {
    super.onRefreshingStateChanged(refreshing);

    if (!refreshing){
        if (mProgressDialog != null && isBackPressed){
            mProgressDialog.hide();
            mProgressDialog = null;
            this.setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
            finish();
        }

    }else{
        if (mProgressDialog == null && isBackPressed){
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Fetching Data",
                    "Please wait while we are updating records ...", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try mProgressDialog .dismiss();

Comment: Don't use `.hide`, use `.dismiss` as @saeed said. Especially when then `finish` is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `cancelable` property of progressbar.

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: @BantiKumar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @BantiKumar anytime :)